# upper bounds for $\int_a^{b} \frac{\exp(x)}{x}\ dx$

Tags: integration, inequality, integral-inequality, upper-lower-bounds

Let $a<b$ be a positive real numbers. Are there tight upper bounds for $\int_a^{b} \frac{\exp(x)}{x}\ dx$, specially asymptotic bounds when $a, b,\frac{b}{a}\to\infty$?

Comment: The given integral is the [exponential integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html).

Comment: What is your progress so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying integration by parts $n$ times gives

\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{b} \frac{e^x}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x
= e^b R_n(b) - e^a R_n(a) + \int_{a}^{b} \frac{n! e^{x}}{x^{n+1}} \, \mathrm{d}x,
\end{align*}

where $R_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(k-1)!}{x^k}$. Now, as $a, b, (b/a) \to \infty $, the last integral is bounded by $\mathcal{O}(e^b / b^{n+1})$, and so, we get

$$ \int_{a}^{b} \frac{e^x}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x = e^b R_{n}(b) + \mathcal{O}(e^b /b^{n+1}). $$

as $a, b, (b/a) \to \infty$, for each fixed $n \geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The integral will be asymptotically $\frac{e^b}b$.

The lower bound
$$
\int_a^b \frac{e^x}x\,dx > \int_a^b \frac{e^x}b\,dx = \frac{e^b-e^a}b
$$
is easy. For an upper bound, for any $c\in(a,b)$ we have
\begin{align*}
\int_a^b \frac{e^x}x\,dx &= \int_a^c \frac{e^x}x\,dx + \int_c^b \frac{e^x}x\,dx \\
&< \int_a^c \frac{e^x}a\,dx + \int_c^b \frac{e^x}c\,dx \\
&= \frac{e^c-e^a}a + \frac{e^b-e^c}c;
\end{align*}
taking $c$ close (but not too close) to $b$, for example $c=b-\sqrt{ab}$ (valid when $\frac ba$ isn't too small), recovers the asymptotic $\frac{e^b}b$.

One takeaway: always try trivial bounds first; and if the integrand (or summand) consists of an increasing function times a decreasing function, try cutting the integral (or series) at an arbitrary middle point and try trivial bounds on each portion separately.